# Best way to extract string from another string based on collection

Tags: c#, string

I have `str` which is a string and I want to check if the last part of string is equal to other string, below I do it manually but lets say I have an array `strin[] keys = {"From", "To", ...}`. If its equal I want to extract (remove) it from `str` and put it inside `key`. What is the best way to achieve that?

```
string key;
if(str.Substring(str.Length - 4) == "From");{
  key = "From";
  //Do something with key
}
else if (str.Substring(str.Length - 2) == "To") {
  key = "To";
  //Do something with key
}
... //There may be more string to compare with
str = str.Remove(str.Length - key.Length);
```

Comment: arrays have a `.Contains` method.

Comment: First, you should start to use [`Strings.EndsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/2333wewz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this makes your `Substring` calls easier and more readable.

Comment: @Dan-o I not interested if it `contains` I interested if it `ends` with certain string

Comment: @schnaader good point I didnt know about that function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `FirstOrDefault` and `EndsWith`.  This will either give you the key it ends with or `null`.  You'll have to include the `using System.Linq` for this to work.

```
string key = keys.FirstOrDefault(k => str.EndsWith(k));
if(key != null)
{
    str = str.Remove(str.Length - key.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a foreach loop to iterate your keys, then EndsWith() to detect and Suc´bString to extract:

```
foreach(string key in keys)
{
    if(str.EndsWith(key))
    {
        int len = str.Length - key.Length;
        result = str.Substring(0, len);
        break;
    }
}
```